# jQuery-Facebox - Popup is not working after repaint from AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebox

I am having a set of Links in my page and I have attached the facebox jQuery functionality so that whenever a link is pressed, it will get a nice popup

```
<a href="coach_selector_popup?day=<%= day %>&hour=<%= hour %>" rel="facebox">
```

Below is the script that I use for 'facebox'ing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox()
  })
</script>
```

The above is working fine. But when I render it again on response to some AJAX call, the functionality is getting lost, meaning when I click on the link I am redirected to a page instead of a facebox popup.

I know that I need to do something when I repaint, can someone point me to the right direction?

**Edit:** I am doing a render partial on my controller like this.

```
render(:partial => "grid_item" , :locals => {:day=>d, :hour=>h)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the javascript code you mentioned inside you partial. I am guessing it will be executed again when loading it. I am not sure if the document.ready event is triggered on a partial update, but i think it is.

Assuming you are using a `link_to_remote` or something similar, you could also use the `:complete` or `:succes` option to add your javascript callback, e.g. like this:

```
link_to_remote get_icon('remove'), 
   :url => {:action => "your_action", :id => @record},
   :success => "jQuery('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();" , 
   :failure => "alert('It failed?')"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey, i am almost there. The   jQuery('a[rel*=facebox]') returns me the entire set of LINK tags. But i need to filter it based on the ID. how to do it ?

Comment: @Bragaadeesh - you can read this link for id selectors... http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/ or more other selectors here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: this answer help me too... I had added jQuery('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox(); in the AJAX response and the problem dissapered... THANK you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

you have to call `.facebox()` again after new elements are added... use a callback function on your ajax...

Comment: can u plz give me the syntax for that ? (i am new to jquery/facebox)

Comment: it depends on how your ajax goes... can you show me some codes?... the render part...

Comment: I can.. but its in ruby-on-rails? Is it fine ?

Comment: well, let's give it a shot... just edit your post above... I may not be of help but there are lot's here in SO that might help...